# encrypted chat java

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, chat

I'm coding a Chat system in java with an encrypted tcp connection.

I understand that I have to use SSL sockets, but besides that how would the code differ from a normal chat system without the encryption? So besides the SSL object, is there anything I need to consider?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

SSL is a transport layer security protocol. it will ensure that your packets are not legible to an eavesdropper (man in the middle).

I would recommend you also incorporate your own application layer security for example to verify the person who you are talking to.

Comment: I know what SSL does (I studied cryptography and internet network systems). I apologise if my question didn't come across correctly. What I'm trying to say is, in the client and server classes, besides the SSL objects, what other things do would I need that are different to a normal client and server class without the tcp encryption. I read something about approved certificates or activating certificates, not too sure what that means. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are referring to SSL certificate signing by validated and trusted certificate authority such as verizon, godaddy or commodo. your SSl certificate (and the party you are contacting) can indeed be self signed and it will be just as secure. the point of certificate signing is AUTHENTICITY not security. in other words, a certificate that is signed by a well known CA is certified to not belong to a nefarious entity posing as someone else. This is important for example for web servers that host e-commerce websites. If a bad guy has a self signed certificate, you will SECURELY hand over your info

Comment: a self signed SSL certificate will serve you just fine, but since you are developing an application with TCP sockets, you will need to have your own **application layer** security protocol in place. for example HTTP which is an application layer protocol can use HTTP basic authentication or HTTP digest authentication.

Comment: thanks! do you have any suggestions for an application layer security protocol besides http basic authentication?

Comment: http is an application layer protocol that is used a lot for web. the internet has many more uses other than web (think SMTP, FTP, VoIP, etc...). if you are using sockets you are working with the next layer in the stack which is the transport layer which means there is no application layer protocol to speak of. You can use TCP or UDP sockets to receive and send packets to your hearts delight. YOU are in charge of your own authentication protocol for example the first packet should always be username and password that you would check against a list or a database.